# Failed when converting the nvarchar value to to data type int and other SQL Server errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a SQL Server table like this:

```
create table LectureNotice
(
    NoticeId int identity(1,1),
    NoticeTitle varchar(50),
    NoticeContent varchar(1000),
    CreatedDate varchar(20),
    LecturerId int,
    CreatedBy varchar(50),
    CourseId int,
    NoticeViewNumber int 
);
```

And I want to insert data into the table using the below query

```
private void btnCrudInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string query = @"insert into LectureNotice values(@NoticeId, @NoticeTitle, @NoticeContent, @CreatedDate, @LecturerId,
            @CreatedBy, @CourseId)";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionHelper("KLAS_DB")))
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoticeId", noticeId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoticeTitle", txtTitle.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoticeContent", txtContent.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", txtCreatedDate.Text.ToString().Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LecturerId", int.Parse(txtLecturerId.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", txtLecturer.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseId", int.Parse(txtCourseId.Text));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("btnCrudInsert" + ex.Message);
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
}
```

When I executed the query few errors occurred. Those are as the following:

1. I try to insert `2021-05-28` in the text box, then the error says `failed when converting nvarchar value to type int`. Even in the SQL Server table I defined `createdDate` as `varchar`.
2. In the `CreatedBy` column when I insert value into, the error also says `failed when converting nvarchar value to type int`.

3. Final error is in the `NoticeContent` I set `varchar(max)` but when I insert value into it through a `text box`, the error says `binary or string value would be truncated`.

Bonus that my `LectureNotice` table is inherited from 2 other tables are

```
create table Course
(
    CourseId int,
    CourseName varchar(50),
    CourseType varchar(50),
    CourseCredit int,
    Enrollment int,
    primary key(CourseId)
);

create table Lecturer
(
    Id int,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    Email varchar(50),
    PhoneNumber varchar(13),
    Department varchar(50),
    LecturerType varchar(50),
    primary key(Id)
);
```

And some filters like

```
alter table LectureNotice 
    add constraint FK_Lnotice_CourseId 
        foreign key(CourseId) references Course(CourseId)
            on update cascade 
            on delete set null;
go 

alter table LectureNotice 
    add constraint FK_Lnotice_LecturerId 
        foreign key(LecturerId) references Lecturer(Id)
            on update cascade 
            on delete set null;
go
```

I've tried and lookup other solutions but no one as same as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always explicitly list the column in the table that you are insert into

```
insert into LectureNotice ( ... )
```

`NoticeId` is an `identity` column in the tble, why are you still inserting value into it `values(@NoticeId ...)` ?

When you do not specify column name in the `insert statement`, `SQL Server` will match first value to the first non identity column. In your case

```
Column `NoticeTitle` to `@NoticeId`
Column 'NoticeContent' to `@NoticeTitle`
Column 'CreatedDate' to `@NoticeContent`
. . .
```

Now do you see the problem ?

Best practice, is always specify the column name in the `insert`

```
INSERT INTO LectureNotice ( NoticeTitle, NoticeContent, CreatedDate . . .)
VALUES ( @NoticeTitle, @NoticeContent, @CreatedDate ...)
```

Comment: You mean that instead write `insert into LectureNotice values(@NoticeId, @NoticeTitle, @NoticeContent, @CreatedDate, @LecturerId,
    @CreatedBy, @CourseId)`. I Need to explicitly write `insert into LectureNotice(NoticeTitle, NoticeContent, ...) values (@NoticeTitle, @NoticeContent....)` ??

Comment: I've tried and it works! Thanks for helping me and gave me a best practice lesson!

Answer (score 0):

This maybe can be a clue, but is it necessary that `CreatedDate` in LectureNotice is a varchar instead date/datetime? I have had some issues in the past writing dates in as varchar and use them as parameters at the database. Sometimes it depends of the user settings which the SQL connection is using.

Try the following

```
create table LectureNotice(
NoticeId int identity(1,1),
NoticeTitle varchar(50),
NoticeContent varchar(1000),
CreatedDate datetime,
LecturerId int,
CreatedBy varchar(50),
CourseId int,
NoticeViewNumber int 
);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", Convert.ToDateTime(txtCreatedDate.Text));
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now);
```

Now, for `NoticeContent`, is this always throwing an exception? What happens if you try the following

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoticeContent", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
```

Comment: I've give a try for your suggestion `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoticeContent", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");` and the same error `binary or string would be truncated in column NoticeContent`. So sucks!!